# Animation of UIButton

Tags: iphone, animation, uibutton, block

I want to create a UIButton that moves random on screen after pressed it. I want to use the animation with blocks. How do this?

Comment: get from here   http://stackoverflow.com/a/1679402/932011

Comment: Thanks for link, but I must use the blocks. How I do?

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Why the down votes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it's a simple example which will animate your button 50 px to the right then back again (don't forget to link myButton in IB) -

.h -

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

.m -

```
@synthesize myButton;

-(IBAction)myButtonPressed {

    CGPoint oldCentre = myButton.center;
    CGPoint newCentre = myButton.center;
    newCentre=CGPointMake(newCentre.x + 50.0, newCentre.y);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                 animations:^{
                     myButton.center = newCentre;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                                           delay:0.0
                                         options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                                      animations:^{
                                          myButton.center = oldCentre;
                                      }
                                      completion:nil
                      ];
                 }
     ];

}
```

You can put whatever animations you like in the blocks.

You might want to think about getting rid of the UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction bits as there could be some amusing results if the user kept touching the button during the animation...