# IOS UIButton with animated gif Image

Tags: ios, cocoa

How to add animated gif file as a default image for UIButton.
I have added gif file as button image. But it is not animating.

Thanks.

Comment: would the [answers to this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679011/implement-animation-in-uibutton) possibly help you?

Comment: no this not relates to my question.. It is the animation when button is pressed. I want to set the default image as animated gif.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Animated GIF won't animate in iphone.. You should add a UIImageView as subview to UIButton, extract all images from your GIF and animate using UIImageView Animation

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.gif"],
                               [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.gif"], nil];
animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0f;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
[yourButton addSubview: animatedImageView];
```

Comment: Which type of button I have to create,, custom ??

Comment: you have to add all images in gif as separate file in xcode bundle too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12155/discussion-between-krishnabhadra-and-shehzad-bilal)

Answer (score 1):

You can not just load a gif file. Save every frame of the gif to a separate image file (png or similar) - you can do that with photoshop for example, then load them into a UIImage using animationImages and do a startAnimating.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS .gif file format is not supported. so avoid using .gif files in iOS

Answer (score 0):

You should explore alternatives to using `UIButton` for that, since it does not allow for such customization. E.g., you could use UIImageView` for your button and set an action for the "touch end" event.